# Get metadata from Azure Data Lake store gen1

Tags: metadata, azure-data-lake

We would like to get the metadata out of the file system. Is there anything like fsImage which stores such a medata information? We used following command:

```
curl -i -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>' 'https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS'
```

But this gives only lists only one level metadata. As per HDFS Api documentation, tried using following command:

```
curl -i -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>' 'https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS_BATCH&startAfter=<CHILD> #added code style
```

But it gives error that it is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with Azur support and they mentioned that not all the methods provided by Hadoop are implemented. So in my case LISTSTATUS_BATCH is not implmented.